# any sugestions on how to manage wal archives on primary

Tags: postgresql

We have a postgres cluster database with primary and 2 standbys. Each of the environment has its own wal_archive folder.

The `archive_cleanup_command` is configured on our standbys so the cleanup is taken care of.

With regards to primary database, if we don't have any backups (as it is non-prod) how can I manage the clean up of the primary wal archives?

Any scripts to handle this via bash and set up as a cron?

thank you

Comment: If you don't have an archive, then there is no need to clean one up.  Maybe you need an archive for some reason, but if so you have to describe that reason to get any meaningful advice.

Comment: sorry dont understand. The primary & standby node have archive_mode enabled. The primary node has 60GB worth of archive from two months old. The standbys are in sync

Comment: Yes, I know they have archiving enabled.  My question is, why?  You have not described any *need* for it to be enabled.

Comment: You are asking why archiving is enabled ? Cause I have a master slave configuration & for recovery purpose

Answer (score 0):

Replication slots were introduced in 9.4. This will arrange to keep each WAL file in the pg_wal directory (not the archive) until all the slot-using replicas are done with it. If you are still using a WAL archive for replication today, you are doing something obsolete or at least non-standard.

If you primarily want the archive for PITR purposes, then *that* is what will need to drive your cleanup decisions.  Once you no longer need a base backup and so remove it, you would then also remove the archive which would only be usable for that base backup.  pgbarman, and I assume every other 3rd party backup solution, will manage this for you.  If you really want the archive both for PITR and for replication (in lieu of slots) then I'm not aware of anything which juggle both of those situations simultaneously.

Your current use of archive_cleanup_command doesn't seem to make any sense.  That is so that the replica can clean up *the master's* archive, not so it can clean up its own archive.  And it only works well for that purpose when there is only one replica, not when there is more than one (which is why slots were implemented).  A replica will automatically retain WAL in its own pg_wal directory until a successful restartpoint frees it up.  To archive on the replica then clean up that archive at every restartpoint doesn't make any sense, just turn off archiving on the replica if that is what you want.

Comment: The archive_cleanup_command is only applicable on standby nodes, it requires that SELECT pg_is_in_recovery be true. The %r place holder is replaced by the name of the file containing that last valid restart point. That is the oldest file that will be required to allow a restored system to be consistent. However, the archive_cleanup_command is not considered on primary systems. Saying that , I am not sure disabling it on standby solves my issue. The issue is on the primary & how to clean up the archives. Are you recommending it be turned off on primary & standby ?